# SQL Injection Prevention use param with method pluck and <<~INFO_SQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have following query.

```
invalid_records
      .unscoped
      .group(:timezone)
      .pluck(<<~INFO_SQL)
        timezone as timezone,
        count(1)
          FILTER(WHERE control_test_id IN (#{table_ids_params}) 
                 AND local_run_at is null 
                 AND timezone = timezone)
          AS records_count,
        array_agg(distinct control_test_id)
          FILTER(WHERE control_test_id IN (["?", #{table_ids_params}]))
          AS control_test_ids,
        array_agg(distinct run_at::text)
          FILTER(WHERE timezone = timezone 
                 AND local_run_at is null)
          AS invalid_run_times
    INFO_SQL



def invalid_records
    scope = Trigger
      .where(control_test_id: table_ids)
      .where(local_run_at: nil)
      .where.not(run_at: nil)

    scope = scope.where(timezone: timezone) if timezone
    scope = scope.where(run_at: run_at) if run_at

    scope
  end


class Trigger < ApplicationRecord
      
      default_scope lambda {
        if $flipper[:explicit_id_ordering].enabled?
          order(position: :asc, updated_at: :asc, id: :asc)
        else
          order(position: :asc)
        end
      } 
      # some code 
    end
```

Query must return result in following format:

```
{
  "Berlin": {
    total: 323,                                    # total count of triggers with given params 
    invalid: 100,                                  # count of triggers with empty `local_run_at` field
    table_ids: [23, 4343, 34, 44],                 # ids of tables invalid triggers belongs to
    invalid_run_times: ["14:00", "23:00", "12:30"] # list of run times of invalid triggers
  },
  "Puerto Rico": {
    total: 3,
    invalid: 1,
    table_ids: [77],
    invalid_run_times: ["13:00"] 
  }
}
```

In filter `FILTER(where control_test_id IN (#{table_ids_params})` need get all control-tests where ids are in table_ids_params. The variable `table_ids_params` is not safe for preventing SQL Injections? is any ways to solve it?

Comment: Would you mind sharing the shape of the involved tables, and the SQL equivalent of the `invalid_records` scope? I have the impression that you do not need part of the filter clauses.

Comment: @rewritten the question was updated with additional information

Comment: ActiveRecord doesn't actually understand and properly typecast the output from `array_agg` - you just get a string.  It might be better to use `json_agg` and use the JSON module to parse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your updated information, it seems to me that you don't need to filter (again) by `control_test_id`, as the filter is applied to the `where` condition. You don't need to add the timezone to the filter, as it is implied by the `GROUP BY` clause.

Then there is a surprising `unscoped` at the start of your chain, why do you  unscope a scope? (Update: based on the default scope you defined, you just need to remove ordering)

If you modify your code as follows, you should be able to get your data right.

```
invalid_records
      .unscope(:oorder)
      .group(:timezone)
      .pluck(<<~INFO_SQL)
        timezone as timezone,
        count(1)
          FILTER(WHERE local_run_at is null 
                 AND timezone = timezone)
          AS records_count,
        array_agg(distinct control_test_id)
          AS control_test_ids,
        array_agg(distinct run_at::text)
          FILTER(WHERE local_run_at is null)
          AS invalid_run_times
    INFO_SQL
```

Comment: thanks. I use filter, because without filter just get all records from DB without grouped by timezone and local_run_at with default values, but I need where local run at is null. How I undestand sql query ignore invalid_records and just  get all records from DB.

Comment: that is very likely because you use `unscope`, which removes all previously set conditions. Try skipping unscope.

Comment: model Trigger has default_scope: order(position: :asc)
If unscope I get error - PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "triggers.position" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: `default_scope`  is a really good way to shoot yourself in the foot as it leads to bugs and unexpected behavior. Write a class method (scope) that does your flipper thingy and use it instead, its going to save your sanity and a lot of debugging time.

Comment: The whole problem with default scope is that there is no good way to just remove the default scope. `unscope` kills it all. What you can do if you insist on `default_scope` is to use `reorder`. But its still smelly and brittle as changing the default scope will cause your code to blow up anyways. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-reorder

Comment: thank you @max. I changed unscope to reorder('timezone desc') and seems is working

Comment: You can just `unscope(:order)` to remove the ordering. I'll edit the answer.